# SQL filter out rows that have multiple column entries

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter out the rows of a table which have multiple entries for a column value. In this example below I want to completely filter out the rows with the name "Tom" and only keep the rows where a person has only one colour. The actual table I am using has long numbers in place of "name" so using the name in the query is not an option.

```
NAME     COLOUR    AGE
-----------------------
James    Green     54
Tom      Blue      45
Tom      Red       45
Harry    Blue      84
Bob      Red       26
```

RESULT:

```
NAME     COLOUR   AGE
----------------------
James    Green     54
Harry    Blue      84
Bob      Red       26
```

Comment: What is your database? Sql server, MySQL...?

Comment: Do you want to skip Tom because he has duplicate rows? Or because his name is Tom?

Comment: The database is SQL server, using MS sql server 2014, I want to skip all Tom's because he has more than 1 entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did not mentioned the database name, this below logic should work most of the database-

You can check the [Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=099573f411288e886f018cab4bfee1ca) created for SQL Server.

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)A
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.Name = B.Name
```

Comment: _filter out the rows with the name "Tom"_? (A bit unclear... is this because of the name Tom, or because he has duplicate rows...)

Comment: "filter out the rows of a table which have multiple entries for a column value" from OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for that:

```
select name, colour, age
from (
  select name, colour, age, 
         count(*) over (partition by name) as name_count
  from your_table
) t
where name_count = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> only keep the rows where a person has only one colour

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.color <> t.color
                 );
```

With an index on `(name, color)`, this is often has the best execution plan (i.e. fastest).

Consistent with your question, this will return *all* rows for a `name` where the colour is the same.